# How to selectively bind attributes in Knockout

Tags: javascript, binding, attributes, knockout-2.0

I wish to set different data-theme attributes depending on the model\object state.
Here I'm just setting 'b' or 'd' for the data-theme attribute (jQuery Mobile).
I can get it to work with:

```
<!-- ko if: $data.id() == $parent.selectedMatchId() -->
    <li data-bind="text: $data.date" data-theme="b"></li>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko ifnot: $data.id() == $parent.selectedMatchId() -->
   <li data-bind="text: $data.date" data-theme="d"></li>
<!-- /ko -->
```

which is a bit ugly.  I thought (hoped) I'd be able to use an expression inside the attribute binder, but the Knockout binding engine doesn't like what I give it.

```
<li data-bind="text: $data.date,
      attr: {'data-theme' : $data.id() == $parent.selectedMatchId() : 'd' ? 'b'}"></li>
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this than the 'ko if' and 'ko ifnot' that I'm using?

Comment: Your 2nd block of code has a malformed ternary, which will prevent the binding from working correctly:  ` ... : 'd' ? 'b'` should be ` ... ? 'd' : 'b'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the template binding. With this binding, you can choose dynamically what template to use.

The documentation is here : http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note_4_dynamically_choosing_which_template_is_used

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use a custom binding that changes my jquery mobile theme. For instance, changing the theme of a button based off a true or false observable value to indicate that the button is selected or not:

**Custom Binding:**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.jqmButtonTheme = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor)
    {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value) ? $(element).buttonMarkup({ theme: 'b' }) : $(element).buttonMarkup({ theme: 'a' });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor)
    {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value) ? $(element).buttonMarkup({ theme: 'b' }) : $(element).buttonMarkup({ theme: 'a' });
    }
};
```

JSFiddle Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/RVLqJ/10/